# Android REST Create Event

Tags: rest, android

I am trying to create an Event on my salesforce Calendar.  All I am receiving is a 400 error.  Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong or missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  OwnerId is correct and startTime and endTime are in correct "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z" format.

Request is made to:   http://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Event

Object sent:  {StartDateTime=2013-10-25'T'12:15:00.000Z, EndDateTime=2013-10-25'T'12:45:00.000Z, Subject=Test meeting from mobile, OwnerId=XXXXXXXXXXXX}

```
private void createSFEvent()  {

        RestRequest restRequest = null;
        try {

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Map createEventInfo = new HashMap();

            createEventInfo.put("OwnerId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            createEventInfo.put("Subject", "Test meeting from mobile");
            createEventInfo.put("StartDateTime", startTime);
            createEventInfo.put("EndDateTime", endTime);

            restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(getString(R.string.api_version), "Event" , createEventInfo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            showError(MainActivity.this, e);
            return;
        }

        client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                showError(MainActivity.this, e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse response) {

                try {
                    Log.d("APITest", "success entered");                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showError(MainActivity.this, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `https` in your endpoint?

Comment: i believe the RestClient takes care of that. I am able to make a sample query and get data.  Just having trouble with this create.

Comment: Try remove the `'` from your date time values: `2013-10-25T12:15:00.000Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have the right format specified for the date time. Remove the single quote characters from your values,

change `2013-10-25'T'12:15:00.000Z` to `2013-10-25T12:15:00.000Z`